# Erro ao comparar duas strings com valor float

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lógica

Boa tarde!

Estou tentando comparar números com Jquery, são valores com casas decimais ou não. quando o valor vai até 999 tudo funciona perfeitamente, porém acima disso não funciona como deveria.

Exemplo:
valor_mo_contrato = 510.00

total_mobra_orc_calc = 1000

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var valor_mo_contrato_s = parseFloat($("#valor_mo_contrato").val()).toFixed(2);
var valor_mobra_s = parseFloat($("#total_mobra_orc_calc").val()).toFixed(2);

  if (valor_mo_contrato_s < valor_mobra_s) {
     $("#valor_unitario_orc_check").text("O Sistema sugere que o Fiscal verifique o valor de Mao de Obra.");
    $("#valor_unitario_orc_check").css({"color": "red"});
  }
});
```

Comment: Andre, provavelmente esta ocorrendo pq seu separador decimal deve estar como virgula e nao ponto. se puder coloca quais valores voce esta entrando em cada campo. editando a sua pergunta

Comment: Esta com ponto, mas existe algum problema por exemplo se um dos numeros vier sem separador? Tipo Um 510.00 comparando com 1000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Voce esta comparando 2 strings usando o operador < pois voce esta usando o metodo `.toFixed(2)` depois de executar o `parseFloat`

Voce precisaria comparar os dois valores diretamente como `Number` e nao como `string`.

Uma das possíveis soluções é você converter novamente com o `parseFloat` na hora de fazer a comparacao no `if`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var valor_mo_contrato_s = parseFloat($("#valor_mo_contrato").val()).toFixed(2);
var valor_mobra_s = parseFloat($("#total_mobra_orc_calc").val()).toFixed(2);

  if (parseFloat(valor_mo_contrato_s) < parseFloat(valor_mobra_s)) {
     $("#valor_unitario_orc_check").text("O Sistema sugere que o Fiscal verifique o valor de Mao de Obra.");
    $("#valor_unitario_orc_check").css({"color": "red"});
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="valor_mo_contrato" value="500.3">
<input type="text" id="total_mobra_orc_calc" value="1000">
<div id="valor_unitario_orc_check"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado meu amigo, resolveu meu problema. Forte Abraço!

Comment: Fico Feliz que a resposta te ajudou! ;)

Comment: @AndreMaia Se a resposta solucionou seu problema marque ela como solução no lado esquerdo.

Comment: Ok Obrigado pela ajuda